# qt jpeg images not showing on deployment (already added the plugins to the directory)

Tags: image, qt, dll

I am using Qt Creator 5.3 but any Jpeg images that I put into the build so not show up when I launch my exe. I got it working before by putting the necessary plugin dlls into the directory but now i still have this problem. In my research the only answer I found was to put the plugin dlls into the directory (which i already did) thank you.

Comment: Where did you put the plugins? In which directory? Please clarify.

Comment: i copied the plugin folders along with the release exe into a separate folder. i also tried copying the plugin dlls "alongside" the exe. both did not work.

Comment: You should place `qjpeg.dll` in a folder named `imageformats` alongside your exe.

Comment: i did exactly that and the images still don't show up :( i also tried placing all the contents of the image formats alogside the exe and all of the dlls alongside the exe without the imageformats folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the image files to a resources file. It is very efficient and it is also cross platform. check out this link http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-resources.html

Comment: thank you! worked perfectly! i still dont know why the images wont load when i just use a jpeg without a resorce, but from now on i'll only use resources. anyways thank you!!